# Did I miss EU customs on a flight from Brazil with stopover in Portugal to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen

e.g. Flight was:

```
Foz do Iguacu (IGU) -> Sao Paulo  [on Azul or Gol, don't remember]
Sao Paulo -> Lisboa [on TAP]
Lisboa -> Munich (MUC) [on TAP]
```

Luggage was checked through from IGU to MUC, in Lisboa I had to pass immigration, but I did not have to go through customs neither had to claim my luggage. In MUC there was no customs present at all, since the flight was Schengen internal, I suppose.

I am on similar flights like once a year and every time I am wondering if I am missing something.

Comment: Are you sure there was no customs signs present at all at Munich Airport? Which terminal did you arrive at?

Comment: I bet there were customs present, you just didnt see them.  Often they arent visible, but passengers will be profiled and anyone they have identified before that point (either by baggage screening before you get your baggage, or by other means) would see some attention when they tried to leave.

Comment: For terminal 2 at least, you should see a customs sign at baggage claim area. There is no systematic check, but you are still supposed to declare if you have something to declare, and random checks (well, sometimes not so random) are conducted to enforce the rules.

Comment: Note that customs officers can quickly identify luggage from intra-EU or extra-EU origins: the former have baggage tags with green edges, the others the regular white.

Comment: Customs will in general be on the final destination, and after baggage claim, because how are they going to inspect your luggage otherwise?

Comment: @JörgWMittag the approach in the USA is to make you collect your baggage at the first airport in the USA, take it through customs, and then re-check it at a dedicated dropoff. Is it different in the Schengen area?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Within EU, usually the first airport will not perform customs check on checked baggage (which is checked through to the final destination), but can check carry-on baggages. The final destination can perform customs check on checked baggage, but not carry-ons (although in practice, carry-ons can still be searched for safety and public security reasons), unless the final destination is a small airport without customs, in which case the first EU airport  will do checks for both checked and carry-on baggage.

Comment: @zhantongz that sounds pretty complicated, is it on the airlines to organise all this?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Mostly the airports, who already have the capability to route and reroute baggages anyway. The airlines just need to apply the right baggage tags.

Answer (score 23):

When you left Munich's baggage claim area for the arrivals hall, you should have had to choose between a green channel and a red channel, and possibly a blue channel.  That was customs.

The blue channel, if there is one, is for people arriving from inside the EU.  Since you were coming from Brazil, you should not have used that channel (despite your stopover in Portugal).  The green channel is for people with nothing to declare to customs, and the red channel is for people who do have something to declare.

Customs officers monitor the green channel and may stop people who are using it, but in my experience this happens very rarely indeed.

Comment: That's what I expected, but I am almost sure we did not walk through any of such lanes. In another occasion, a friend of mine brought lots of "Velho Barreiro" sprit from brazil, and wanted to declare it and was actively looking for customs officers in Bremen, but customs were not present neither.

Comment: Similar experiences, if I recall correctly. It's a EU flight, exit is trivial.

Comment: (+1) Note that luggage checked in inside the EU have green stripes on both sides of the tag. You could remove it before going through the customs channels, travel without hold luggage or even apply fake tags after collecting your luggage but apart from that, it's very easy for customs agent to see at a glance where your luggage came from originally.

Comment: @MarcWittke You have to walk out one way or the other, the theory is still the same: all flows are mixed at the luggage claim level, declaration at the very end of the journey rather than the first flight into the EU, spots checks to enforce all this. Sometimes the lane is a sliding door with a green sign rather than a full corridor with colored walls, the only EU airport I saw another setup is Toulouse (which is much smaller than MUC): the red “lane” was a phone on the wall you were supposed to use if you didn't qualify for the only exit (which was marked green).

Comment: @MarcWittke: "That's what I expected, but I am almost sure we did not walk through any of such lanes." – The "customs area" is simply the exit of the baggage hall. The only way you would not pass through customs is when you don't claim your baggage, in which case the amount you could smuggle is limited to what fits in your carry-on

Comment: I'm wondering if your last paragraph is correct. Shouldn't they be monitoring the blue channel since that is only for travelers within the EU and they want to make sure on one is using that wrongfully?

Comment: @Relaxed TLS is far from the only airport which only has a phone for customs declarations; plenty of smaller airports do that.

Comment: @gsnedders I am sure but as I wrote it's the only one I encountered *within the EU* (saw plenty of that elsewhere). It's not *that* common in an airport getting a significant amount of commercial traffic (as TLS is). And even if there is no agent present and you are supposed to use a phone, usually there is still a separate door or corridor, at least in my experience.

Comment: @Relaxed Even in one of baggage claim areas of FRA I encountered a phone on the wall because the customs officers are frequently not on-site.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus With only one exit and no red door or corridor?

Comment: @Relaxed I remember the phone, but no corridor or separate door. My guess is that I would've noticed them if present

Comment: @Relaxed I checked: there is only one exit, about 10 meters wide, that has a small green frame for *nothing to declare*. A couple of meters next to it, there is a tiny, inconsiderable door to a small customs office, which is unstaffed by default. Besides the door is the red phone to call an officer. Due to this big discrepancy, you wouldn't notice that they're supposed to be two different channels on first glance.